# \rule command produces very faint lines

Tags: rules

the \rule command produces very faint lines as below--how to make it dark black

[image]

code used

```
  \rule{3mm}{.1pt}%
  \rule[-3mm]{.1pt}{1cm}%
  \rule{3mm}{.1pt}%
```

Comment: Use something bigger than `.1pt`? That is going to look very faint because it is so thin. It is black by default and there's no such thing as 'dark black'.

Comment: A ‘light black’ would be some grey…

Comment: The graphics guidelines of the American Math Society (http://www.ams.org/arc/graphics/graphics-guidelines.pdf) say to always use a rule no less than .5pt at 100%.  Granted, that is for printed copy, but the same principle applies to copy to be shown on a screen.  .5pt is probably heavier than you want, but anything less than .2pt might disappear completely depending on the screen resolution and the positioning of the rule on the page relative to the screen raster.